# How do i get an object of its location attributes

Tags: java, object, vector, aabb

I'm using axis-aligned bounding box methodology to get the closest entity to the player, I calculate the closest entity based on its vectors, I want to decrement the health of the entity but I don't have that entities object, I only have its vectors, how can I get the entity object from just its vector coordinates.

the code that I'm using to calculate the closest entity object vectors is

```
        AABB box = null;
    //
    // getting closest box
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[i] != null) {
            if (box == null)
                box = boxes[i];
            Vector2f length1 = box.getCenter().sub(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, new Vector2f());
            Vector2f length2 = boxes[i].getCenter().sub(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, new Vector2f());

            if (length1.lengthSquared() > length2.lengthSquared()) {
                box = boxes[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Entire entity class

```
public abstract  class Entity {

protected int health; 
public static final int default_health = 10;

private static Model model;
protected AABB boundingBox;

// private Texture texture ;
protected Transform transform;



protected Animations[] animations;//array for player animations
private int useAnimation;// which frame to start at



protected boolean active = true;



protected float x, y;
protected int width, height;
protected Rectangle bounds;


//
// changed to protected so any child class will have access to that
//
public Rectangle getCollisionBounds(float xOffset, float yOffset){
    return new Rectangle((int) (x + bounds.x + xOffset), (int) (y + bounds.y + yOffset), bounds.width, bounds.height);
}
public Entity(int maxAnimations, Transform transform) {

    this.animations= new Animations[maxAnimations];

    this.useAnimation = 0;

    this.transform = transform;
    boundingBox = new AABB(new Vector2f(transform.position.x, transform.position.y), new Vector2f(transform.scale.x, transform.scale.y));//scales bounding box
    health = default_health;
}
public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}
public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}
public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public void setAnimation(int index, Animations animation) {//sets animation
    animations[index] = animation;
}

public void useAnimation(int index) {//select animation
    this.useAnimation = index;
}

public void move(Vector2f direction) {//tells if player has moved
    transform.position.add(new Vector3f(direction, 0));
    boundingBox.getCenter().set(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);// updates center of bounding box
}

public abstract void update(float delta, Window window, Camera camera, World world);

public void collideWithTiles(World world) {// put in new method because we want the world to handle every entity

    AABB[] boxes = new AABB[25];//surrounds entity with 5*5 bounding boxes

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            boxes[i + j * 5] = world.getTileBoundingBox(

                    (int) (((transform.position.x / 2) + 0.5) - (5 / 2)) + i,
                    (int) (((-transform.position.y / 2) + 0.5) - (5 / 2)) + j);
            // gets everything around player for
            // bounding boxes
        }
    }   
    AABB box = null;
    //
    // getting closest box
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[i] != null) {
            if (box == null)
                box = boxes[i];
            Vector2f length1 = box.getCenter().sub(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, new Vector2f());
            Vector2f length2 = boxes[i].getCenter().sub(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, new Vector2f());

            if (length1.lengthSquared() > length2.lengthSquared()) {// used squared to save cpu power
                box = boxes[i];
            }
        }
    }
    //
    // colliding with it
    //
    if (box != null) {
        Collision data = boundingBox.getCollision(box);
        if (data.isIntersecting) {
            boundingBox.correctPosition(box, data);
            transform.position.set(boundingBox.getCenter(), 0);
        }


        //
        // next closest box
        //

        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            if (boxes[i] != null) {
                if (box == null)
                    box = boxes[i];

                Vector2f length1 = box.getCenter().sub(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, new Vector2f());
                Vector2f length2 = boxes[i].getCenter().sub(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, new Vector2f());

                if (length1.lengthSquared() > length2.lengthSquared()) {// used squared to save cpu power
                    box = boxes[i];
                }
            }

        }
        // coliding with it
        data = boundingBox.getCollision(box);
        if (data.isIntersecting) {
            boundingBox.correctPosition(box, data);
            transform.position.set(boundingBox.getCenter(), 0);
        }

    }
}




public abstract void destroy();


public void render(Shader shader, Camera camera, World world) {
    Matrix4f target = camera.getprojection(); 
    target.mul(world.getWorldMatrix());
    shader.bind();
    shader.setUniform("sampler", 0);
    shader.setUniform("projection", transform.getProjection(target));
    animations[useAnimation].bind(0);//binds texture at animation
    model.render();
}

public static void initialiseEntity() {// initialise the model
    float[] vertices = new float[] { -1f, 1f, 0, // top left 0
            1f, 1f, 0, // top right 1
            1f, -1f, 0, // bottom right 2
            -1f, -1f, 0,// bottom left 3

    };

    float[] texture = new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,

    };

    int[] indices = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, };

    model = new Model(vertices, texture, indices);
}

public static void deleteEntity() {// get rid of model
    float[] vertices = new float[] { -1f, 1f, 0, // top left 0
            1f, 1f, 0, // top right 1
            1f, -1f, 0, // bottom right 2
            -1f, -1f, 0,// bottom left 3

    };

    float[] texture = new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,

    };

    int[] indices = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, };

    model = new Model(vertices, texture, indices);
}


public void collideWithEntity(Entity entity) {// method for coliding with just entites
    Collision collision = boundingBox.getCollision(entity.boundingBox);// get all data so we can colide with the entity using aabb

    if (collision.isIntersecting) { // test if it is intersecting
        collision.distance.x/=10;//leaves smaller gap when moving entity objects
        collision.distance.y/=10;
        //return entity.active(false);

        boundingBox.correctPosition(entity.boundingBox, collision);// correct the position
        transform.position.set(boundingBox.getCenter().x, boundingBox.getCenter().y, 0);// setting the transform

        entity.boundingBox.correctPosition(boundingBox, collision);//corect entities bounding box with our bounding box
        entity.transform.position.set(entity.boundingBox.getCenter().x, entity.boundingBox.getCenter().y, 0);//set its transformation position

    //collision.h
    }
}


public void hurt() {
    health -= 10;
    if(health<= 0) {
        active = false;

    }


}
```

Comment: Well you'd have to have some relation of the box to the entity that box represents. It's hard to tell without knowing more about your application and what libs you're using. If I'd have to guess I'd assume the entity at the same index as the bounding box would be the one you're after - so keep track of the index of the closest bounding box as well.

Comment: @Thomas I'm using the LWJGL library, I am keeping track of the next closest bounding box, this works for the collision but the values of the entities are stored as Vectors  and I'm trying to get the closest entity object so I can edit the entity attributes of that entity object

Comment: I'm not that familiar with LWJGL but doesn't it allow you to shape your entities/objects in any way you want? In that case you'd be responsible for syncing entity movement/position and their bounding boxes - and thus you already should be able to make a connection between entities and their BBs.

Comment: @Thomas im not really understanding your solution, could I give you a link to the project's repository and the class location, and you could use that to reference it from?

Comment: You could do that but I'd rather suggest you post the relevant parts here for others to see as well (think about someone revisiting that question in the future). Also I might not have the time to sift through a lot of code so I'd appreciate you doing that - you're the author of that code after all. That being said, I actually didn't propose a _solution_ but was trying to provide a hint: if there's already a connection between an entity and the BB (which should be the case in order to place the BBs correctly) then you should be able to traverse that connection in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Thomas i have edited the question so it has the entire abstract Entity class, I hope this will suffice, i understand that this is a big task and understand if you do not have the  capacity to do the task

Comment: Hmm, given that model it would probably be best to feed a `this` reference to the AABB. If that class doesn't provide for that a decorator or subclass might be necessary. Alternatively you could iterate over the entities and use `==` comparisons to get the entity that references that exact BB. That might be slow though so if you can first reduce that list of entities to potential candidates (e.g. by spatial sorting or indexing) that would help a lot. However, just directly maintaining the link would probably be best in your setup.